# Choose a specific regular language to prove a language is not regular

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages, closure-properties

[image: question]

I've tried a few tricky languages such as D = { w | w has an equal number of occurences of 01 and 10 as substrings} but I don't have the means to prove this one as being not regular (and I cannot confirm if it is or not). I know of the pumping lemma, which I have used on very basic languages to prove they are not regular, but I'm not even sure where to begin on this one.

Comment: Don't use images as main content of your post. This makes your question impossible to search and inaccessible to the visually impaired; [we don't like that](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/752/should-we-do-anything-about-questions-that-are-just-a-scan-of-a-problem-in-their). Please transcribe text and mathematics (note that you can [use LaTeX](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/271/add-short-reference-for-latex-commands)) and don't forget to give proper attribution to your sources!

Comment: The part "how do I prove that a language is not context free?" is a duplicate. Your question as a whole is not necessarily; which other D did you try? What do you think makes a language "tricky"?

Comment: Hint: think of languages that you know not to be regular. Try to express them as $C(A)$.